# What happens if I format my iPod Touch 2G?

Tags: ipod-touch, unix, disk-format

Because when you connect it to Ubuntu, it sees iPod touch as a usb device and I think it allows to format it also. So, I wonder what would happen if I format my iPod Touch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS doesn't expose a "real" filesystem over USB. On my work Windows PC (without iTunes installed), one can see only the photos, and Windows recognizes it as a camera. (Also, it won't let you format it.)

So, since it's a fake filesystem, it probably won't accept the formatting commands.

If you try it, please tell us what happened!